# How do the PIL ImageFilter enhancement filters work?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

Where can I find information on what algorithms the PIL ImageFilter functions use? Like how does edge_enhance work? I'm looking to implement a difference of Gaussians filter but if PIL has a filter that works similarly I'll use that.

Answer (score 2):

The ImageFilter methods all use kernels convolved with an image to produce the filter effects. [Here](http://www.aishack.in/2010/08/convolutions/) is good primer on kernel convolution. If you load the ImageFilter module you can figure out the kernels used for each kind of operation by looking at

```
>>> help(ImageFilter)
```

For example, for EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE help gives

> filterargs = ((3, 3), 1, 0, (-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1))

This means that the EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE kernel is size 3x3, scale factor 1, offset 0, and consists of -1 values except for the center value, which is 9. From what I've read it seems like you can create a custom filter (including a difference of Gaussians kernel) by supplying the appropriate arguments to a Kernel object:

```
Kernel(size, kernel, scale=None, offset=0)
```